# How to implement collapsing toolbar with no toolbar

Tags: android

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-App-ToolBar

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

I saw an example, I've implemented a toolbar.

Toolbar for example, works as follows.

1) Expanded

[image]

2) Collapsed

[image]

But, I want to show the background, or the toolbar is transparent when the toolbar is collapsed.
How can I implement the following?
Like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the background is transparent when the toolbar is collapsed make sure that the `contentScrim` is not set to transparent.

Here is an example of wht your layout might look like.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Collapsing Layout in your layouts,

```
app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
```

**Example**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a transparent background through layout XML use:

```
app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
```

To do it programmatically:

```
collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
collapsingToolbar.setStatusBarScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. Can I remove the toolbar? Remove toolbars, how do I look only at the bottom of the background?